# How to import whole SCSS folder in Vue Nuxt project?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, nuxt.js

At my company we are not writing css in Vue files, we prefer to do it the *old* way with `SCSS`.

Problem is, we end up with a need of writing new import in `styles.scss` any time we create new component, and it really bugs me in bigger projects.

Not so long ago, when I have been developing in React, I imported module called `node-sass-glob-importer` in `webpack.config` file, tweaked a bit ([you can check here](https://github.com/Tinmar3/React_template_01172019/blob/ca27821aacfd7ca0370fbf791208f967fb2b6ff0/config/webpack.config.js)) and it worked - I could have imported folder like this: `@import "components/**";`

In Nuxt, I only have `nuxt.config.js` file and I am lost a bit. I know how to extend some simple stuff there, but this seems to be more complicated.

Any help of importing `node-sass-glob-importer` or doing the same thing in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module and than:

```
export default {
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/style-resources'],
  styleResources: {
    scss: [
      './assets/yourFolder/*.scss'
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, even for external modules from node_modules. :)

I only wonder. I still need to have `css: ['~/assets/style/style.scss'],` for this to work, but why? That file is now empty, as I moved all my imports to nuxt.config.js.

Comment: Now I realised that every time I make new scss file, I need to manually restart server because it doesn't update by itself. This is only downside by now, wish I could force severs somehow to reload when I create new file, same way it does when I change something in nuxt.config.js

Comment: Please check the warning https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module#warning - you are using the module wrong if you use it for styles

Answer (score 1):

You can use `node-sass-glob-importer` in Nuxt like this:

nuxt.config.js:

```
const globImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');

export default {
  ...
  css: [
    '~/assets/scss/global.scss'
  ],
  ...
  build: {
    extend(config, {loaders: {scss}}) {
      const sassOptions = scss.sassOptions || {};
      sassOptions.importer = globImporter();
      scss.sassOptions = sassOptions;
    }
  }
}
```

global.scss:

```
@import "./assets/scss/base/*";
@import "./assets/scss/components/*";
```

styleResources is used for things like variables, mixins and functions that you want to use anywhere in your SCSS without having to import the files.